# High score lists with combined result

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I've been searching for a solution to create a highscore list, and found that I could use the large formula and an index match to search up the name. However I come up short when I want a list where I have the names alongside with the combined score?

EDIT: By combined result I mean the high score should rank players by the total sum of their results in column B.

Each week a different person will be 'playing' and will have a score for that week. This image of my data might clear things up a bit.

[image: image of my data]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but you've got to do a little more first: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's OK, although that's a very unspecific comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MATCH and MAX, to return the row number of the highest score. Then use INDEX against the 'Responsible' column, and 'Highscore' column.

```
Highest Score: =MAX(D1:D4)
Row of highest score: =MATCH(MAX(D1:D4), D1:D4)
Index the responsible: =INDEX(B1:B4, MATCH(MAX(D1:D4), D1:D4))
```

Combine the 'Responsible' and their 'Highscore'

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(MAX(D1:D4),D1:D4)) & " (" & INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(MAX(D1:D4),D1:D4)) & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is the same result I got, but this only gives me the top player, and his highest score. I'd like for it to be the combined score of the player throughout all the weeks.

So for Bob that would be 206 for example.